# Show default district when areas from region selected in Odoo10

Tags: python-2.7, api, odoo, onchange, odoo-10

i have 3 districts and some areas related to these district. Now, i want that when i select area than related district default show in next field, no need to fill district. for this my code is below:

**Python Code:**

```
class district_code_form(models.Model):
    _name = 'district.districe.code'
    _rec_name = 'district_value'

    district_value = fields.Char('District Value')
    district_region = fields.One2many('district.district', 'district_id', string="District Workflow")

class district_form(models.Model):
    _name = 'district.district'
    _rec_name = 'district'

    district_id = fields.Many2one('district.district.code', string='Districts Id', ondelete='cascade', index=True, copy=False)
    district = fields.Char("District")
    district_code = fields.Char('District Code')
```

**Now i want to access this configuration table for this my code is here:**

```
class customer_information(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"

    @api.onchange('district_table_case', 'district_table')
    def _onchange_district_table(self):
        print "A:", self.district_table_case.district_region
        print "B:", self.district_table_case.district_value
        rec = self.district_table_case.district_region
        res = self.district_table_case.district_value
        print "res:", res
        if res:
            return {'domain': {'district_table_case': [('id', 'in', res)]}}
        else:
            return {'domain': {'district_table_case': []}}

    district_table = fields.Many2one('district.district')
    district_table_case = fields.Many2one('district.districe.code', change_default=True,
                                          default=_onchange_district_table)
```

i am getting all ids on terminal screen but not getting upto the mark

Thanks in advance.

Comment: whare is the area table ?

Comment: district.district is area table {'district = fields.Char("District")'}

Comment: It is like when we select 'state' than respective 'country' auto fill. That's kind of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just use `district_table_case` as a [`related` field](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#fields)?

Such as:

```
class customer_information(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"

    district_table_case = fields.Many2one('district.districe.code', string="Region", related="district_table.district_id")
```

In this way, it will always point to the Region assigned to the district.